# How do I create this shape in CSS? (vertically align div)

Tags: css, css-shapes

How do I create this in css? I'm having trouble aligning the circle divs vertical middle.

See image:
[image: http://siterepository.s3.amazonaws.com/4015/facebook.png]

Here what I've done: https://jsfiddle.net/5odbwkn5/

```css
 .gray-btn1 {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: url(../images/ico/9.png) no-repeat center 70%;
     background-color: #5dd6e4;
     margin-left:-20px;
     position: relative;
     float:left;
 }
 .gray-btn {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: url(../images/ico/9.png) no-repeat center 70%;
     background-color: #5dd6e4;
     margin-right: -20px;
     position: relative;
     float:right;
 }
 .gray-mid {
     background-color: #5dd6e4;
     text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="gray-mid">
    <div class="gray-btn1"><span class="fa-connectdevelop">left</span>
    </div>
    <div class="gray-btn"><span class="fa-connectdevelop">right</span>
    </div>
    <div style="height:100px">middle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using any image as background to create the round effect? If yes, use `background-position: x y` else you can use `margin-top` property to align the rounded edges.here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5odbwkn5/2/

Comment: you can use before and after instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use pseudoelements as before and after to make easily that effect:

```
.container:before {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    height: 30px;
    width:30px;
    background-color:#999;
    border-radius:15px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-15px;
    top:7px;
}
.container:after {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    height: 30px;
    width:30px;
    background-color:#999;
    border-radius:15px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-15px;
    top:7px;
}
```

here is the **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5odbwkn5/12/)** I made for you as an example.

Edited: I updated the fiddle to be sure that the circles ("before" and "after") are positioned behind the container. And move slightly the elements to make it more simillar to your image.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not duplicate styles. Instead, extend common `btn` styles with specific for left button.

You can position buttons in the middle with the help of `position: absolute` relatively to the parent and `top: 50%`, `margin-top: -25px` fixes vertical offset in this case.

As the result it will become:

```css
.gray-mid {
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #5dd6e4;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}
.gray-btn {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: url(../images/ico/9.png) no-repeat center 70%;
    background-color: #5dd6e4;
    right: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
.gray-left {
    left: -20px;
    right: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray-mid">
    <div class="gray-btn gray-left"><span class="fa-connectdevelop">left</span></div>
    <div class="gray-btn"><span class="fa-connectdevelop">right</span></div>
    <div style="height:100px">middle</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5odbwkn5/4/) what you're looking for?

There are multiple ways which you can achieve vertical centering. There's even a really easy to follow guide posted [by Chris Coyier here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) that you can reference whenever you need.

This is basically what I go to when I need to center something vertically.

```
.parent-with-centered-content {
  position: relative;
}

.parent-with-centered-content > .child-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo elements for this kind of functionality, and position them accordingly.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gray;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}
div:before {
  left: -10px;
}
div:after {
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div>This is some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not try to match your fonts, but using background image, and just a little css, here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/z8z3h75h/

```
<div id="background">
<div class="left">
FACEBOOK
</div>
<div class="right">
become a fan
</div>

</div>

#background {
background-image:url(http://s28.postimg.org/loa285ugt/1_SEOh.jpg);
    width:409px;
    height:41px;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px;
    color:white;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    margin-right:40px;
    color:white;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do that is to set `top: 50%` and translate or set margin on :pseudo elements

```css
:root{text-align: center;padding: 40px 0 0 0}

.container{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 10px
}
.container, .container:before, .container:after{
  background: #a6a195;
}
.container:before, .container:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px; /** height/2 **/
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%
}
.container:before{left: -10px}/** width/2 **/
.container:after{right: -10px}
.container div{display: inline; color: white}

.container .txt1{margin-right: 20px}
.container .txt2{font-size: 12px}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="txt1">FACEBOOK</div>
   <div class="txt2">Become a fan</div>
</div>
```